# In firefox my jquery click function does'nt work, MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, click

In my controller.js I've function:

```
$(MyModel.addMyButtonTag).live("click", function () {
    MyModel.addRecord();
});
```

and in my model.js I've:

```
var MyModel = {    
    addMyButtonTag: "#AddButton",

    addRecord: function () {

       //Show modal
       $(MyModel.addMyButtonTag).modal();
       $('#simplemodal-container').css('height', '230px');
       $('#simplemodal-container').css('min-height', '0');
   }
}
```

These jqueries work well in IE8-9 but in firefox they don't work at all. Any suggestion please?

Comment: live() is deprecated... use on() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery .live() is deprecated  Use .on() instead

for more info take a look here http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: same prob with on(). I'm using numerous partial views so thatswhy I'm using live()

Comment: You can try use bind ( http://api.jquery.com/bind/), but after refresh model you wil have to bind again

Comment: Welcam)) if i help you please click rep)))

Answer (score 2):

```
addMyButtonTag: "#AddButton"
```

Can`t find comma at the end.

Comment: yeah misprint, i've just checked the live code. anyway good pick, thanks

Comment: @newbie_developer For whatever reason you have edited the question? The comma is a syntax error and 'live' is more performance issue, a lot of sites still are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class "MyModel" defined before your live function.Include your class defination js first.

Its worked for me :

```
<input type="button" id="AddButton" />
<script type="text/javascript">

        var MyModel = {
            addMyButtonTag: "#AddButton",
            addRecord: function () {

                //Show modal
                alert("ITS OK");
            }
        }


    $(MyModel.addMyButtonTag).live("click", function () {
    MyModel.addRecord();
});


</script>
```

Comment: good suggestion thanks, i've used bind() instead live() which has done a trick, ta